# how to configure nginx to indicate ’/‘ to my main page

Tags: django, nginx, web-deployment

i have a django project and my web static files are at `'web/'` directory

here is the structure:

```
➜  web git:(ycw.alpha) tree -L 4
.
└── forward
    ├── asserts
    │   ├── img
    │   │   ├── background
    │   │   ├── qr
    │   │   └── thumb
    │   └── style
    │       ├── css
    │       └── sass
    ├── index.html
    ├── package.json
    ├── script.js
    ├── source
    └── unit
```

i have configured Nginx conf and i want nginx to directly indicate to `'web/forward/index.html'` when i request my own website `'http://example.com'`

i do the thing above like this:

```
location / {
     index index.html
     root /path/to/my/django/project/;
}

location /index.html {
     alias /path/to/my/django/project/web/forward/index.html;
}
```

it indeed directly redirects to `'index.html'`, but the question is there are some references in `'index.html'` to some static files such as img or css and the paths are relative paths like `'./asserts/style/css/index.css'` so consequently these files are not found as 404

how can i configure it correctly?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken there's an extra `/` at the end of `root`'s value

Comment: you should have a common prefix for all your static files, so you don't need relative paths, but just `/static/path/to/image`. That way you can add a `/static` route to nginx pointing to `/project/web/forward/assets/`. In your `index.html` just use `/static/img/my_image.png` or `/static/style/css/base.css` (no preceding `./`).

Comment: @fernandezcuesta i suppose that's not the point. Mainly because of the relative paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by changing 'root' in **location /** to `'/path/to/the/index/directory'` **rather than the root directory of the django project**, in this way you can still use relative paths of static resources in html file generally.